# Cohen reals satisfying a formula

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing

Consider the Cohen forcing $\mathbb{C}  =Fn(\omega,2)$, the one that adds a Cohen real, and now suppose that for a Cohen real $r$ generic over $V$ we have $$V[r]\models \exists x (x \in \mathbb{R} \wedge x \not \in \dot V \wedge \varphi(x) )$$ where $\dot V$ is the "name" (actually the definition) of the ground model and $\varphi$ is a formula with parameters in the ground model.
Now my question: is there a condition $p\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $$p\Vdash \varphi(\dot c)$$ where $\dot c$ is the canonical name for the generic object?
In other words, if in the generic extension there is a new real satisfying $\varphi$, is there a condition that forces that the generic Cohen real satisfies $\varphi$?

Ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No; consider for example $\varphi(x$) = "Every other bit of $x$ is $0$." No Cohen-generic real has this property, but if $c$ is Cohen-generic then the "spaced out" version of $c$ $$0,c(0),0,c(1),0,c(2),...$$ is not in $V$ but does satisfy the property $\varphi$.

---

What *is* true is that every new real is "equivalent to" a Cohen real in a precise sense: assuming $\mathsf{V=L}$ for simplicity, if $c$ is Cohen over $L$ and $d\in L[c]\setminus L$ then $d\equiv_ce$ for some Cohen real $e\in L[c]$. Here "$\equiv_c$" is the relation of equivalent **constructibility degree**: we say $x\le_cy$ iff $x\in L[y]$. (If we don't assume $\mathsf{V=L}$ we need to replace $\equiv_c$ with the "mod $V$" analogue.)

This can be seen by looking at the possible factors of the Cohen algebra (I think Jech has a good writeup of the details). Note, however, that there is no $\varphi$ occurring here; this is just a property of newly-added reals.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!